# how to create a language form validation

Tags: javascript

I made an input how can I limit it just writing with one language?

```html
<input type="text" name="user" id="user">
```

and if somebody wrote with other languages it shows alert.

Comment: What's an "other language"? How would you even begin to define that?

Comment: @tadman i think i try to tell the spoken language using in the input text.

Comment: It means, for example, you should just write the field in English, not like german.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to tell the difference between English and German because the two languages are notorious for stealing words from the other. Same goes for English and pretty much anything. Is "[schadenfreude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude)" English? It's used in English and contains only English letters...

Comment: the only one alternative in javascript is detecting the browser language, no alternative detecting on encoding you need server side language i guess. For a detection browser just do a : **navigator.language**

Comment: Cul de sac......

Comment: @headmax Many people use English sites despite having their computer's locale set to something else.

Comment: You shoud not brother validating the input's language. It's not worth. Just leave a message on the page for the user.

Comment: @tadman yes :) right 100%

Comment: sounds like people will write gibberish like "123" just mess with you :] and Google translate seems to detect gibberish as English ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer to this is: You can't do it.

The way you can address this is by doing a few things:

- Restrict which characters are allowed. For example, `a-zA-Z0-9_-` are the usual set allowed for things like usernames. Reject with an error or strip out any invalid characters.
- Apply a minimum and maximum length.
- Scan for disallowed phrases, like profanity or slurs, though the list of all profane words and their variants is the size of a dictionary, so this is often a losing battle.

Now if someone puts in "coördinate" it'll fail validation even though *technically* that is valid in English, but I'm sure they can deal. Likewise if someone puts in "tequila" or "shuriken" even though those words are technically not English-origin, they're in common use and are in most English dictionaries. Astonishingly few English words are actually English origin. It's a language that seems to sponge up flavor and smells from just about anything it comes into contact with.

Answer (score 0):

As per @tadman's answer, you may consider this bellow code:

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" onkeyup="checkLang();">
<script>
function checkLang(){
    var user = document.getElementById("user");
    if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test( user.value ) == false) {
        alert("You've entered non English character[s]");
    }
}
</script>
```

By this above code you can show an alert for non-English character to your user.

Comment: How can we include Turkish characters in this Regex code? For example; `ş,ğ,ç,ö`